# Solve $y''-2y'+y=2\cos{x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble knowing when my ansatz is wrong. For example if my ansatz to this is $y_p=a\cos{x}+b\sin{x},$ I get nowhere. How can I make a correct ansatz and are there any general rules to determine proper ansatz?

**Note:** I know one can sovle this using eulers formula and all that but that's not the point here. So please no posts that have nothing to do with the method of undeterminate coefficients.

Comment: your ansatz is right

Comment: Ok, please solve this for me here. I want to see how it is right.

Answer (score 1):

we have
$$y'(x)=-a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$$
$$y''(x)=-a\cos(x)-b\sin(x)$$
then $$-a\cos(x)-b\sin(x)-2(-a\sin(x)+b\cos(x))+a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)=2\cos(x)$$
from here we get
$$\cos(x)(-a-2b+a)+\sin(x)(-b+2a+b)=2\cos(x)$$
thus $$b=-1$$ and $$a=0$$

Answer (score 0):

It's all okay, your $y_p$ is correct.

$2\cos x=y_p''−2y_p'+y_p=-a\cos{x}-b\sin{x}-2(-a\sin{x}+b\cos{x})+a\cos{x}+b\sin{x}=2a\sin x-2b\cos x$

so $a=0$ and $b=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $y_p=a\cos x+b\sin x$, we have that $y_p'=-a\sin x+b\cos x$ and $y_p''=-a\cos x-b\sin x.$ Then, we have that 
$$ y_p''-2y_p'+y_p=-a\cos x-b\sin x+2a\sin x-2b\cos x+a\cos x+b\sin x=2\cos x.$$
Collecting the coefficients, we see that $-2b-a+a=2$ and $2a-b+b=0$ so that $b=-1$ and $a=0$. Thus, the function $y=-\sin x$ solves the differential equation.